# QUITAR ceros de un numero

Tags: sql, reportviewer

Buenas tardes soy nuevo en programacion sql y he estado investigando como quitar los ceros a mis tarifas por ejemplo tengo tarifas en una misma columna
0.7550
100.00
pero en mi reporte no quisiera que se muestren los decimales 00 del lado derecho y solo se muestre
0.75
100
Favor su gentil ayuda 
Gracias de antemano

Comment: que gestor de bases de datos? que llevas intentado? con que lenguaje del backend trabajas? esto debe formatearse desde la base de datos y por que? por que no darle formato cuando los datos lleguen a la vista tal vez

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow , en primer lugar te invito a hacer el [tour] para ganar unas medallas y saber como funcionamos, tambien te invito a leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y darnos un ejemplo minimo verificable asi los usuarios que visitan este sitio recurrentemente gustosamente te ayudaran

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te pueden votar negativamente porque no sabemos lo suficiente sobre tu base de datos.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(campo as decimal(16,2)) as alias from tabla
```

Esta considero yo que es la consulta ideal para tu caso, espero te sea útil hermano.

Answer (score -1):

Con esta consulta que te indico devolverías el número sin decimales:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(CAMPO,0,1) AS int) As valor FROM TABLA
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos